# Page template with custom query instead of archive-xxx.php?

Tags: custom-post-types, customization

I have created a custom post type and I would like to list the posts. I have choosen a page template with a  custom query instead of archive-xy.php to list the posts because the user would like to edit the content on the page. The custom query works, but if I create a page with slug XY and I open the page, the template is not working, I only see the the default layout (index.php). I've renamed it to for example to xy-2 and it works.

Is it possible to disable the domain.com/xy, because it's using the blog layout? (because no archive-xy.php).

Comment: do you need more info, or is it clear?

Comment: No, it is not at all clear.

Comment: So, I created a custom post type with the "career" slug. After that I created a page template with my custom layout for this post type, and with a custom query. Everything works, the template list my posts. But.. If I type http://domain.com/career to the browser I see the posts but the layout is different, because It's using the index.php file for layout. I know I can create archive-career.php with my custom layout, but It's not perfect for me because I can't edit the content. So I don't want my visitors, to see domain.com/career only domain.com/career-page what is a page, with a page template

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem going on. I had a custom post type Vacatures which I wanted to display with a page-vacatures.php.

But the layout was completely messed up. After digging through every file in my theme, I figured out that the webpage used archive.php.

Setting `'has_archive'=>false` solved my problem because Wordpress wouldn't search for an archive file but for the template file (page-vacatures.php) that I specified.

@Rinoleti: Have you tried saving your permalinks again? After changes to a link I always save the permalinks again because Wordpress can do weird stuff after changing a slug or something like it.

Comment: The problem have alread been solved, as you can see the OP has posted his solution (very poor effort though). Actually like your solution more because of the detail given.

Comment: I posted this because I've read in the comments that they wanted a better explanation.

Thanks for your positive feedback.

Answer (score 0):

`'has_archive' => false` and everything works.

Because I can create a page with career slug, if this value is true everytime when I opened domain.com/career I saw the layout for the normal blog posts, it used the index.php template

Comment: Please explain **why** that could solve the problem.

Comment: because I can create a page with career slug, if this value is true everytime when I opened domain.com/career I saw the layout for the normal blog posts, it used the index.php template.

Comment: Please improve your _answer_, don’t hide important information in comments. :) The next reader with the same problem should get a guide, easy to understand, nicely explained.

Comment: btw I don't know why if I rename the page's slug to career2, and i open domain/career2 it redirects me to /career